# SQL Server Full Text Search - how to return the matched phrase(s)

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, full-text-search

I'm using the **Full Text Search** on Azure SQL Database with a corpus of news articles. Both the `CONTAINS` and `FREETEXT` methods work fine, but i need to  <kbd>highlight</kbd> the matched words in the articles. Is there any way to retrieve the word(s) that matched on the search for each row ? The `CONTAINSTABLE` & `FREETEXTTABLE` methods provide matching rank per row, but not the matched element. Could anyone point me to the Microsoft Documentation if such functionality does exist ? Not sure if it might be relevant, but be aware that *Semantic search*, *thesaurus* and *search property lists syntax* are **not** supported with this kind of Database. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: As per my knowledge there is no built-in function to highlight the text in sql.

Comment: No built-in function indeed, but here's one using FTS internal searching logic to do the highlighting, try [Hit Highlighting for SQL Server](https://www.interactivethoughts.com/products/thinkhighlight/).

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/35717c10-dd62-487e-a89a-db8b5c6e6ebf/highlight-found-words-using-full-text-search?forum=sqldatabaseengine) We don't have any inbuilt functions to highlight the matching words using SQL.

By using free-text search we can return the entire document (or an excerpt) and point out the words or phrases that helped match that document to the search.
I created user defined function (UDF) using below code:

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[HighLight](@text NVARCHAR(MAX), @searchWord NVARCHAR(4000), @style NVARCHAR(4000), @Len INT)
RETURNS  NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @cr NCHAR(1)
      DECLARE @length INT  =  0
      DECLARE @lp INT  =  0
      DECLARE @pl INT  =  0
      DECLARE @pos INT  =  0
      DECLARE @marg INT
      DECLARE @word NVARCHAR(4000)
      DECLARE @ret NVARCHAR(MAX) =  ''
      DECLARE @positions TABLE  
      (
           Sent  INT,
           Lin INT
      )
      DECLARE cur1 CURSOR  FOR
     SELECT display_term FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(N'FORMSOF(FREETEXT, "'  + @searchWord +  '")', 1033, 0, 1)

     OPEN cur1
     FETCH  NEXT  FROM cur1 INTO @word
     WHILE  @@FETCH_STATUS  =  0
       BEGIN
          WHILE  1  =  1
          BEGIN
            SET @pl =  CHARINDEX(@word, @text, @pl)
            IF @pl <=  0  BREAK
            SET @lp =  LEN(@word)
            IF @pl >  0  BEGIN
            SET @cr =  SUBSTRING(@text, @pl -  1, 1)
            IF @cr <>  ' '  AND @cr <>  NCHAR(9) AND @cr <>  NCHAR(13) AND @cr <>  NCHAR(10) BREAK
          END
        INSERT  INTO @positions (Sent, Lin) VALUES(@pl, @lp)
       SET @pl = @pl +  LEN(@word)
      END
      FETCH  NEXT  FROM cur1 INTO @word
    END
    CLOSE cur1
    DEALLOCATE cur1

   DECLARE cur2 CURSOR  FOR
   SELECT  Sent, MAX(Lin)
   FROM @positions
   GROUP  BY  Sent
   ORDER  BY  Sent

   SET @marg =  LOG(@Len) *  5
   IF @marg > @Len /  4  SET @marg = @Len /  4
   SELECT @pos =  MIN(Sent) - @marg FROM @positions  
OPEN cur2
   FETCH  NEXT  FROM cur2 INTO @pl, @lp
   
   WHILE  @@FETCH_STATUS  =  0  AND @length < @Len
   BEGIN
     SET @ret = @ret +  SUBSTRING(@text, @pos, @pl - @pos)
     SET @ret = @ret +  '<span style="'  + @style +  '">'  +  SUBSTRING(@text, @pl, @lp) +  '</span>'
     SET @length = @length + @pl - @pos + @lp
     SET @pos = @pl + @lp
   
     FETCH  NEXT  FROM cur2 INTO @pl, @lp
  END

  CLOSE cur2
  DEALLOCATE cur2

 SET @marg =  LOG(@Len) *  5
 IF @marg + @length < @Len SET @marg = @Len - @length
 IF @marg >  0  SET @ret = @ret +  SUBSTRING(@text, @pos, @lp)
 RETURN  '...'  + @ret +  '...'

END
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I tried above function with sample text

```
SELECT [dbo].[HighLight](

'40 Liters glass fish tank with lid, hangon filter and air pump. I will throw in 6 guppies for you to start up the tank. Great for kids, beginner or as a present.The tank has no leaks or scratches, sell due to upgraded to a bigger tank.Please note, it doesn''t come with a heater.If you have any questions, please contact me.',
'leak or scratch',
'background-color:yellow;font-weight:bold',
50)
```

Output:

[image]

Highlighting is related frontend that's why we are getting style is as it is in SQL.
In website you will get like this

[image]

It will work kindly try this UDF.